# PHP set active link on page using includes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, include, navigation

So I have searched SO for an hour trying to find the answer, and also tried various methods, [including this](http://webdevjunk.com/coding/css/17/php-menu-includes-with-css-style-to-highlight-active-page-link/)

I am trying to include my pages, along with the navigation. But on the correct page, I need the list-item to have a class of `active`. The navigation is in header.php and currently looks like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="active"> <a href="/">Home</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Apps</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Forums</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

First, I have no idea if JS(jQuery) would be better, or if PHP was to be better. Both wouldn't matter if it works.

Also I am a bit new with PHP and trying to learn.

What would be the easiest (hopefully) method to use? So I don't have to change a lot of code just to give a nav `class="active"`

Comment: how do you getting the values to set active class on that page, are you using query string variable to get page id. something like **exmaple.com?page_id=Apps**

Comment: I am not that advanced in PHP yet..... It's really just static pages with PHP.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Asumming you have a `$page` variable (which contains the name of the page you are currently on):

```
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="<?php echo ($page == "home" ? "active" : "")?>"> <a href="/">Home</a> </li>
      <li class="<?php echo ($page == "apps" ? "active" : "")?>"> <a href="#">Apps</a> </li>
      <li class="<?php echo ($page == "forums" ? "active" : "")?>"> <a href="#">Forums</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Could you explain how would the $page variable look? and would the variable be on the inc file or the page I am going to include the nav on? Really new to PHP here.

Comment: if you place `<?php $page = "home"; ?>` on your included homepage then Home will be set as active. Don't forget to setup the CSS either.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple way where you do not need to add any other variable

```
<li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/index.php" ? "active" : "");?>">
<a href="index.php">Start</a>
</li>
<li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/about.php" ? "active" : "");?>">
<a href="about.php">About</a>
</li>
<li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == "/practices.php" ? "active" : "");?>">
<a href="practices.php">Practices</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `basename` function before `$_SERVER`. I hope it will work.

```
echo (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'yourPageName' ?'active' : " ");
```

Comment: the perfect Answer , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At page header use:

```
<?php $loc = this.location; ?>
```

Then at every link add:

```
<?php(this.href == $loc) ? echo 'class="active"' : '' ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

define variable $page="index.php" in index.php page and for other pages change the variable value according to the page name

```
<li class="<?php echo ($page == "index.php" ? "active" : "")?>">
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="<?php echo ($page == "about.php" ? "active" : "")?>">
    <a href="about.php">About</a>
</li>
<li class="<?php echo ($page == "service.php" ? "active" : "")?>">
    <a href="service.php">Services</a>
</li>
<li class="<?php echo ($page == "contact.php" ? "active" : "")?>">
    <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$page_url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

$s = explode("&",$page_url);
//print $s[0];
$page = $s[0];

function createTopNav($page)
{
    $pages = array(
        array(
            'name'=>'Feeder',
            'link'=>'page=feeder'
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'Services',
            'link'=>'page=services'
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'Development',
            'link'=>'page=development'
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'Design',
            'link'=>'page=design'
        ),

    );
    $res = "";
    foreach($pages as $key=>$val)
    {
        if($val['link']==$page)
        {
            $res.= "<a class=\"active\" href=\"?"
            .$val['link'].
            "\">"
            .$val['name'].
            "</a>";
        }
        else
        {
            $res.= "<a class=\"\" href=\"?"
            .$val['link'].
            "\" >"
            .$val['name'].
            "</a>";
    }
    }
    $res.="";
    return $res;
}

echo createTopNav($page);
```

Comment: It's better if you can add some explanation, or as comments.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using query string `exmaple.com?page_id=Apps` to pass page id than with php you can
approach this thing

$page_id = $_REQUEST['page_id'];

```
 <ul>
          <li class="<?php echo ($page_id == "Home" ? "active" : "");?>">
 <a href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="<?php echo ($page_id == "Apps" ? "active" : "");?>">
 <a href="#">Apps</a>
          </li>
          <li class="<?php echo ($page_id == "Forums" ? "active" : ""); ?>">
 <a href="#">Forums</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: That is waaaay too hackable :-P

Comment: @neal i don't know how he is getting the current page name, it's just about an idea to approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jQuery or PHP - can do next:

1. Give ID or different CLASS to each `<li>` element in "your-include-nav.php".
2. Define the "active" style with CSS in `<head>` section, on each page.

Answer (score 0):

Add basename function. Then it will work i hope.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $home = "  ";
    $about = " ";
    $service = " ";
    $team = " ";
    $contact = " ";
    $cond = " ";
    if (isset($_GET['contact'])) {
        $contact = "active";
        # code...
    } elseif (isset($_GET['about'])) {

        $about = "active";
    } elseif (isset($_GET['service'])) {

        $service = "active";
    } elseif (isset($_GET['team'])) {

        $team = "active";
    } elseif (isset($_GET['cond'])) {

        $cond = "active";
    } else {
        $home = "active";
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).