# PHP: How to securly set active link on page using includes

Tags: php

in an earlier post "PHP set active link on page using includes" there was a comment "That is waaaay too hackable". can you explain to me how it is hackable and how i can duplicate this idea with a safer method.

```
$page_id = $_REQUEST['page_id'];

 <ul>
          <li class="<?php echo ($page_id == "Home" ? "active" : "");?>">
 <a href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="<?php echo ($page_id == "Apps" ? "active" : "");?>">
 <a href="#">Apps</a>
          </li>
          <li class="<?php echo ($page_id == "Forums" ? "active" : ""); ?>">
 <a href="#">Forums</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

I am building my first plugin for a website and i need to have links that php sets to active if you are on the page such as home or statistics. so the installation may be at www.website.com/home/plugin/statistics. I need to be able to set the class

statistics to active if they are on the page without knowing how many layers deep in their website my plugin is installed.

Comment: There's no security risk in the code you posted. But if you don't sanitize user input when doing other operations it could be a security risk.

Comment: But, you don't necessarily want to append `?page_id=Forums` to every URL on your site.

Comment: Please link to the earlier question. You mention includes, and therein probably lies the vuln if you are including based on the value of `$page_id`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski it looks like it is from this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8476437/689579

Comment: @Sean Hmmm, doesn't actually appear to be anything harmful in there. It's actually pretty tidy. The worst that could happen is for the end user to manually supply `?page_id=` in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach may be something like this:

In the page files (`about.php`, `index.php`, etc.) provide the unique identifier at the very top of the page:

```
<?php
$page_id = 'home';
require_once('_menu.php');
```

Separate your navigation into a file `_menu.php` to be included.

```
 <ul>
          <li class="<?php echo ($page_id == "Home" ? "active" : "");?>">
 <a href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="<?php echo ($page_id == "Apps" ? "active" : "");?>">
 <a href="#">Apps</a>
          </li>
          <li class="<?php echo ($page_id == "Forums" ? "active" : ""); ?>">
 <a href="#">Forums</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```