# Adding active class to parent and child element when child is active with PHP

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, submenu

Is there a solution for whenever the child element `Subpage1.php` or `Subpage2.php` is active, so that the parent element `practices.php` also gets the `class="active"`?

```
<ul>
    <li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == " /index.php " ? "active " : " ");?>">
        <a href="index.php">Start</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == " /practices.php " ? "active " : " ");?>">
        <a href="practices.php">Practices</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == " /subpage1.php " ? "active " : " ");?>">
                <a href="subpage1.php">Subpage1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == " /subpage2.php " ? "active " : " ");?>">
                <a href="subpage2.php">Subpage2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[A similar question was asked here, but the parent child problem couldn't be solved there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476225/php-set-active-link-on-page-using-includes/32969916#32969916)

Answer (score 0):

This is not optimal, but you could check the value of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` against both the element and its children using [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
<li class="<?php echo (in_array($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], array(
        '/practices.php',
        '/subpage1.php',
        '/subpage2.php',
    )) ? "active " : " ");?>">
    <a href="practices.php">Practices</a>
    ...
</li>
```

If `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` matches any of the items in that array, the class will be set to active. It might be less cumbersome than a loop.